# Disable collapse button in actionbar - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, button, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have a problem with Button in Action Bar. So why i create Button in Action Bar **it only collapse never show icon**. This is my menu

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_home"
    android:title="Home"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:orderInCategory="0"/>
```

And this is my screen:
[image]

Comment: can you explain in precisely ?

Comment: yes, but i wanna it show icon home

Comment: show activity code.

Comment: MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_items, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

Comment: and onOptionSelected: int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_name) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(IndexActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

Answer (score 0):

try like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_home"
    android:title="Home"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="1" /> </menu>
```

and

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_name:
                //your code//
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_home"
        android:title="Home"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="100"/>
</menu>

Comment: check udpated answer.

Comment: now, one more try, try replacing whole code of yours with mine as provided in my answer and inform me.

Comment: i tried replacing your code, but it always collapse.